# How to add observer for subviews.count in UIView?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to detect when number of subviews changes and perform a job then. How to add an observer and get a callback when it changes?

So far I have tried within `AppDelegate`:

```
private func setupObserver() {
    window?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "subviews.count", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    print(keyPath)
}
```

but it crashes:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '[<__NSArrayM 0x6000002520f0> addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:] is not supported. Key path: count'

Comment: If you're unsuccessful adding the observer, you can always swizzle the addSubview method and call the original implementation and your custom handler afterwards.

Comment: Ok, in other words I try to detect when sth in view hierarchy was changed, for example If I presented a new controller on the screen as a modal, or sth else. I need to detect this... can you help me with this?

Comment: Did you try to observe `subviews`, without count? There's a chance it might help.

Comment: subviews as `[UIView]` doesnt have a method `addObserver`

Comment: I meant keypath:  `subviews`, not `subviews.count`.

Comment: hmm... I try it soon

Answer (score 2):

Another solution apart from the KVO

You can subclass `UIWindow` as below

```
class MyWindow: UIWindow {
  override func didAddSubview(_ subview: UIView) {
    print("Subview added")
  }
}
```

Then in `AppDelegate` you can override the `window` property as below

```
var _window: MyWindow?
var window: UIWindow? {
  get {
    _window = _window ?? MyWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    return _window
  }
  set { }
}
```

Now whenever a new object is added your overridden method `didAddSubview` will be called. You can override more methods according to your need.

[didAddSubview(*:)*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622500-didaddsubview),
[willRemoveSubview(:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622647-willremovesubview),
[willMove(toSuperview:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622629-willmove),
[didMoveToSuperview()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622433-didmovetosuperview)

Excerpt of [`window`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623056-window) property

> The default value of this synthesized property is nil, which causes the app to create a generic UIWindow object and assign it to the property. If you want to provide a custom window for your app, you must implement the getter method of this property and use it to create and return your custom window.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
import UIKit

typealias ObserveHandler = (UIView) -> Void

var keyUIViewObservingHandler: UInt8 = 0xe

extension UIView{
    func observingRemoveFromSuperview(){
        let parent = self.findObserverParent()
        self.observingRemoveFromSuperview()

        self.notifyObservingParent(self, parent: parent)
    }

    func onDidAddSubview(_ subview: UIView){
        self.notifyObservingParent(subview)
    }

    private func notifyObservingParent(_ subview: UIView, parent: UIView? = nil){
        if let observingParent = parent ?? self.findObserverParent(){
            observingParent.getObservingHandler()?(subview)
        }
    }

    private func findObserverParent() -> UIView?{
        return self.superview?.findObserverParentPvt()
    }

    private func findObserverParentPvt() -> UIView?{
        if self.isObservingHierarchy(){
            return self
        }else{
            return self.superview?.findObserverParentPvt()
        }
    }

    private func isObservingHierarchy() -> Bool{
        return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &keyUIViewObservingHandler) != nil
    }

    func observeHiearachy(handler: ObserveHandler){
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &keyUIViewObservingHandler, handler, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
    }

    private func getObservingHandler() -> ObserveHandler?{
        return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &keyUIViewObservingHandler) as? ObserveHandler
    }

}
```

Make sure to swizzle these methods in the AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        self.setupViewHierarchyObserving()

        return true
    }

    func setupViewHierarchyObserving(){
        let originalSelector = #selector(UIView.didAddSubview(_:))
        let swizzledSelector = #selector(UIView.onDidAddSubview(_:))

        let viewClass = UIView.self

        let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(viewClass, originalSelector)
        let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(viewClass, swizzledSelector)

        let didAddMethod = class_addMethod(viewClass, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod))

        if didAddMethod {
            class_replaceMethod(viewClass, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod))
        } else {
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
        }

        let originalSelector2 = #selector(UIView.removeFromSuperview)
        let swizzledSelector2 = #selector(UIView.observingRemoveFromSuperview)

        let originalMethod2 = class_getInstanceMethod(viewClass, originalSelector2)
        let swizzledMethod2 = class_getInstanceMethod(viewClass, swizzledSelector2)

        let didAddMethod2 = class_addMethod(viewClass, originalSelector2, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod2), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod2))

        if didAddMethod2 {
            class_replaceMethod(viewClass, swizzledSelector2, method_getImplementation(originalMethod2), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod2))
        } else {
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod2, swizzledMethod2)
        }
    }
```

Now you can observe the view hierarchy as simple as:

```
self.view.observeHiearachy(handler: { (subview) in
     // your code here
        })
```